# JQuery Cycle Plugin Not Working When Hidden Div Becomes Visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using http://jsfiddle.net/Jk59f/

What do I do to get the cycle plugin working when 1 of these hidden div is visible?

edit: Updated JFiddle to show the exact problem.  now you can see the slider anchors dont work at all.

Comment: Just to verify you want to start cycle after one of the item links is clicked? is that correct?

Comment: yes.. the cycle has a pager so 1 of the anchors has to be clicked but thats not workin so just to get the plugin working is what im tryin to do

Comment: When asking questions try and making it as easy as possible for those answering your questions. jsFiddle includes a handy 'TidyUp' button to clean up your javascript code. You also posted a ton of html without bothering to at least give it proper indentation.

Comment: @mrtsherman edited the link sorry about that! I forgot to indent and didnt know about the TidyUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem now. The issue is that you wipe out your slideshow with the following lines.

```
var contentTobeLoaded = $("#workitem" + id).html();
$('#ajax').html(contentTobeLoaded)
```

When you copy html you don't copy the event handlers associated with the elements. It looks like in the end you expect the images to be loaded via ajax. So what you will need to do is call the cycle plugin AFTER all the elements have been loaded via ajax. You can't just call it at the beginning of your scripts and expect it to work with newly loaded elements.

Comment: I kinda got it working.. I moved the script from the javascript to load after the images http://jsfiddle.net/UN9zu/ but you said that its because when html is copied it doesnt copy the event handlers associated with the elements.. is there a way to get it to copy over the event handlers so I dont have to repaste the javascript over and over for every #workitem?

Comment: I don't really know how to answer this because your code structure makes zero sense to me. You can use jQuery's `clone` which creates a deep copy of a set of elements. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to accomplish then a better system can be worked out. Be very detailed. What is the point of the ajax code? What happens when user clicks on item1? Will there be more items, what is your expectation when those items are clicked.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a "projects" page on my portfolio website. the "Item 1" link along with more links will be image links of project thumbnails and when clicked, The page will scroll to the top with ScrollTo (not added yet) and then it will slide down the dark bg and fade in the content which would be Title, Summary, External Link, and the JQuery Cycle Plugin to cycle through the images.  Here are examples http://www.trokit.com/work & http://www.iamyuna.com/ just click one of the images..  And thanks for the help! I appreciate it!

Comment: how do I do this with jQuerys clone if its the correct solution for the description above?

Comment: I can't solve your problem because I don't think what you are doing makes sense. Try and implement something around this framework I am providing. http://jsfiddle.net/de6n7/1/